# If an Entity Might Have Image, Is it Better to Store Boolean in Database or Use file_exists Each Pageload?

Tags: php, performance

### Background

I have a database which contains entities (employees). The entity might have an image, might not. These images are stored as files on the server.

### Problem

When I load up a PHP template to display the entity, I don't want to display an empty `<img>` tag.

### Question

I currently use `file_exists` to run a check to see if the entity's matching image file exists. Would it be better to instead add a field to by database store a Boolean, set when creating the entity, and use that to determine whether to write the image?

Comment: What's the DB data if no image is stored? Can't you just check for an empty value rather than use `file_exists`?

Comment: False Vs True? I'm thinking of something in the initial form. I have an image uploader as part of the form, which separately uploads the image to the server when the form is submitted. I could add a hidden field, with false or true as the value, set by the image upload Javascript, and send that to the database.

Comment: Ah I see - you're not storing paths - you're just accessing `images/employeed/<id>.jpg`? Your best bet would be to set a boolean (a REAL boolean in MySQL is a `TINYINT(1)`) _when_ the user uploads their picture. That said, unless you ABSOLUTELY need the extra performance (and there's nowhere else you can shave this off) simply use `file_exists` and cache the value if nessesary.

Comment: Why not save the image path in the database. That way you can have a default image for any entity that does not upload an image. Or you could store the actual image data in the database. Either way I feel like your current approach could run you into some problems down the line